# Parameterized Spring bean configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have a hierarchy of beans:

```
<bean id="a">
  <property name="config" value="something"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b">
  <property name="a" ref="a"/>
</bean>

<bean id="c">
  <property name="b" ref="b"/>
</bean>

<bean id="d">
  <property name="c" ref="c"/>
</bean>
```

This all works. However, let's say I now need an alternative hierarchy where I change some things on the deepest bean, in this case `a.config`. In order to wire everything up, I now need to double the whole hierarchy, i.e.:

```
<bean id="a2">
  <property name="config" value="something2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b2">
  <property name="a" ref="a2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="c2">
  <property name="b" ref="b2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="d2">
  <property name="c" ref="c2"/>
</bean>
```

I know of two workarounds:

- Use properties, i.e. something like this

  ```
  <bean id="a">
    <property name="config" value="${a.config}"/>
  </bean>
  ```
- Use global beans and override them, i.e.

  ```
  <bean id="a.config">
    <constructor-arg value="something"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="a">
    <property name="config" ref="a.config"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Override in another xml file -->
  <bean id="a.config">
    <constructor-arg value="something2"/>
  </bean>
  ```

Drawbacks:

- Properties only allow for simple value changes. E.g. I cannot change the class of the instantiated bean if their properties are not the same
- Overriding is non-deterministic and nobody wants to debug issues related to non-deterministic Spring instantiation

Is there some other way to do this that's more manageable, pass the parameters down somehow?

Logically I'm after something along these lines:

```
<bean id="a">
  <property name="config" ref-param="a-config"/>
</bean>

<bean id="b">
  <property name="a" ref="a"/>
</bean>

<bean id="c">
  <property name="b" ref="b"/>
</bean>

<bean id="d">
  <property name="c" ref="c"/>
  <param name="a-config" value="something"/>
</bean>

<bean id="d2">
  <property name="c" ref="c"/>
  <param name="a-config" value="something2"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Why not use Java config? I think this problem is not critical at all if you use Java config and IDE.

Comment: @MaxFarsikov I wish. Legacy code.